# Druid - longSum metrics is not populating

Tags: java, hadoop, apache-superset, druid

I am doing batch ingestion in druid, by using the wikiticker-index.json file which comes with the druid quickstart.

Following is my data schema in wikiticker-index.json file.

```
{  
   type:"index_hadoop",
   spec:{  
      ioConfig:{  
         type:"hadoop",
         inputSpec:{  
            type:"static",
            paths:"quickstart/wikiticker-2015-09-12-sampled.json"
         }
      },
      dataSchema:{  
         dataSource:"wikiticker",
         granularitySpec:{  
            type:"uniform",
            segmentGranularity:"day",
            queryGranularity:"none",
            intervals:[  
               "2015-09-12/2015-09-13"
            ]
         },
         parser:{  
            type:"hadoopyString",
            parseSpec:{  
               format:"json",
               dimensionsSpec:{  
                  dimensions:[  
                     "channel",
                     "cityName",
                     "comment",
                     "countryIsoCode",
                     "countryName",
                     "isAnonymous",
                     "isMinor",
                     "isNew",
                     "isRobot",
                     "isUnpatrolled",
                     "metroCode",
                     "namespace",
                     "page",
                     "regionIsoCode",
                     "regionName",
                     "user"
                  ]
               },
               timestampSpec:{  
                  format:"auto",
                  column:"time"
               }
            }
         },
         metricsSpec:[  
            {  
               name:"count",
               type:"count"
            },
            {  
               name:"added",
               type:"longSum",
               fieldName:"added"
            },
            {  
               name:"deleted",
               type:"longSum",
               fieldName:"deleted"
            },
            {  
               name:"delta",
               type:"longSum",
               fieldName:"delta"
            },
            {  
               name:"user_unique",
               type:"hyperUnique",
               fieldName:"user"
            }
         ]
      },
      tuningConfig:{  
         type:"hadoop",
         partitionsSpec:{  
            type:"hashed",
            targetPartitionSize:5000000
         },
         jobProperties:{  

         }
      }
   }
}
```

After ingesting the [sample json](https://dl2.pushbulletusercontent.com/ARHUvDD1bglU2Fpunc8BYgj48hknLnpu/wikiticker-2015-09-12-sampled.json). only the following metrics show up.

[image]

I am unable to find the longSum metrics.i.e added, deleted and delta.
Any particular reason?

Does anybody know about this?

Answer (score 0):

<sup>OP confirmed [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45007683/druid-longsum-metrics-is-not-populating#comment77025829_45007683) from [Slim Bougerra](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5953288/slim-bouguerra) worked:</sup>

> You need to add yourself on the Superset UI. Superset doesn't populate the metrics automatically.